# to be a hat meaning

Tags: meaning-in-context

'The man *who thinks he is a hat* was hanging on the coat rack in the entryway'

What is the meaning of the word 'hat' in this sentence?
It is from a grammar book, where it is given as an example of dependent finite relative clause.

Comment: Is there a word missing? I might be able to understand 'The man who thinks ...', but at the moment it simply doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Buy a better book on English grammar. "The who thinks" is not grammatical. If there is a noun between "The" and "who," then the sentence becomes grammatical (though not necessarily sensible). The word "hat" refers to a kind of covering for the head.

Comment: I can name the source if needed. In the original text the italics part stands for the dependent clause, I believe.

Comment: In my adding the italics the word 'man' was erased and I had to type it again. Excuse me, my mistake.

Comment: Oliver Sacks, a well-known (and sadly, now deceased) neurologist wrote a popular-science book about curious brain malfunctions entitled "The Man Who Mistook His Wife for a Hat", in which one of the chapters describes a man with [visual agnosia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_agnosia).

Comment: The word 'hat' is a noun meaning 'covering for the head'. The sentence is perfectly OK. "The man who **thinks** (present tense, used about a well-known and persistent fact) he **is** (ditto) a hat (he has a persistent and continually existing delusion that he is a hat) **was** (past tense, OK) hanging (like a hat might well do) on the coat rack in the entryway". I think he might have preferred to be on a hat stand, but that is nit picking.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Should I understand the sentence as ' The man who thinks himself a hat...' ?

Comment: I believe Dr Sacks' patient actually mistook his wife for a hat _stand_ - he made a grab at her face instead of collecting his hat on leaving the consulting room.

Comment: Well, no idiom in the sentence is present, right? It must be taken literally.